# Exposing database data to custom clients over the internet

Tags: c#, web-services, service

I am looking to make a service or console application that will wait for communication from a client application, run queries depending on the data received and return the query results to the client application.

The reason for this is to remove the database access information (username, password, database, etc.) from being hard-coded into the client. This will also lessen the amount of processing required to be done by the client. Therefore the service or console will need to be able to handle multiple connections at once and process them quickly.

The data received by the service will be coming over the internet or on the local intranet so it will need to be able to listen on all ports or can be told to listen on a single port.

Visually it would look like this;

[image: Console / Service]

Any reference material or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think this question deserves a downvote, but I also don't think I can vote up to counteract the downvote.

Comment: @MitchWheat: Agreed. Already done that :). Also, it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: Thanks, Mitch. I'm not sure why it was down voted to begin with. Constructive feedback is always welcome.

Comment: My initial reaction was to close (apologies), because it seemed too general. If it were more searchable, it may be more useful to future visitors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could expose your data in several ways:

- [WCF service(s)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) with several operations for exposing different entities/data sets. You could expose HTTP/HTTPS or TCP/IP endpoints, which are some of the most commonly used ones.
- [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx) ([OData protocol](http://www.odata.org/) implementation). This allows a more flexible way of exposing data to clients. You're presenting clients with a series of REST endpoints (which is also HTTP(S)), but they have much more flexibility in telling your server component what data to return, by being able to specify all kinds of filters. The better part here is that you won't have to do much on the server side in order to satisfy different types of queries (as opposed to normal WCF services, where you'd have to create one operation for each query, generally).

These are the options I'd examine. 
The server component could be either a Windows Service, in which case you'd be restricted to classical WCF services or a Web Service Application to be hosted in IIS.

You can now look in depth at these two technologies. Giving you code snippets for this is almost impossible, since they won't be easily readable snippets but a whole lot of code.
I suggest you first get acquainted with the ideas behind these two options and then try to look at some code.